# How to consume WCF service in Windows8 HTML5/JS app?

Tags: javascript, wcf, html, iis, windows-8

I'm developing a win8 app, that should consume a WCF service hosted on IIS, but it wont...
NOTE: The Web service works just fine. I've tested it with the WCF Test Client in VS2012
Here's my code:

IService.cs:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

[OperationContract]
string SitePredmeti();

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
List<Profesor> SiteProfesori();
}
```

i made two methods: one returns xml one returns json just so i can test which one works. it doesn't matter whether the WS returns json or xml, i can work with either in the app.

i use the default SPLIT APP TEMPLATE for a html5/JS app in win8 WITHOUT ANY CHANGES. for now i just need to consume the wcf service, i'll deal with the data templates later.

the url to my iis hosted wcf:

```
http://localhost/InformatorWS/Service.svc
```

here's what i've tried so far:

```
var baseURl = "http://localhost/InformatorWS/Service.svc/SitePredmeti/";
var url  = baseURl+Number1.value+"/"+Number2.value;  
WinJS.xhr({ url: url  }).then(function  (r)  {
var result  = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
ResultSpan.innerHTML  = result;  });
```

the error i get here is:

> {"exception":null,"error":{},"promise":{"_oncancel":null,"_nextState":null,"_state":>{"name":"error","done":null,"then":null},"_listeners":null,"_value":{},"_isException":false,"_errorId":2},"id":2}

next i tried calling it via jquery ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        //Calling WCF Service using jQuery ajax method
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: "false",
            url: "http://localhost/InformatorWS/Service.svc/SitePredmeti",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (result) {
                //AjaxSucceeded(result);
                alert('ok')
            },
            error: alert('ne ok')
        });
    });
```

and when i link jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script>
```

i get three exceptions:

> Unhandled exception at line 10, column 2 in
>   ms-appx://66b782f9-8814-4b8e-a2e3-d6e73893690a/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

(and two of these - for the two alert in success and error)

> Unhandled exception at line 8, column 9 in
>   ms-appx://66b782f9-8814-4b8e-a2e3-d6e73893690a/js/default.js
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'alert' is undefined

anyone have any idea what i am doing wrong? or just anyone know any way of consuming a WCF service hosted on IIS?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Include jquery before jquery UI, that should fix your jquery undefined issue.  You could try allowing get on the webservice and see if you can consume it using a browser.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a couple of issues at play here. You need different endpoints to be consumed by the WCFTestClient and JavaScript. For the first, you need a SOAP endpoint, but for the second you need a non-SOAP (a.k.a. REST) endpoint. Since you didn't mention in your question, I'm assuming you only have one endpoint, and since the WCFTestClient works, it's a SOAP endpoint, which doesn't work for JavaScript <sup>1</sup>. If this is the case, add a new Web endpoint to your service (or replace the one you have with that)<sup>2</sup>. You can read more about web endpoints in the [WCF Web HTTP Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172.aspx) doc at MSDN.

---

<sup>1</sup> In theory, it's possible to call SOAP endpoints with JavaScript (especially if the endpoint is using some simple binding like `BasicHttpBinding`). But you'll need to create the **XML** payload to send to it, and format it according to the SOAP specification - not the JSON payload which you're sending and expecting as a result.

<sup>2</sup> And if you do that - have only one, non-SOAP, endpoint, WCF Test Client will not work with it anymore, [but that's expected, since it tries to consume the service WSDL to talk to it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx).